# How to add validation rules with messages in jQuery validation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've tried below code but can't get error messages.

```
var v = jQuery("#account_info").validate({
    //errorLabelContainer: $("#result"),
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({                               
           target: "#checkOut_error",                   
            success: function(msg) {
                //setTimeout("window.location='MyBids.php'", 2000);             
                if(msg == '<?php echo OBJECT_STATUS_SUCCESS;?>')    {
                    $('#checkOut_error').html('<div class="msg msg-thanks">Bid Submitted Successfully !</div>');
                    //setTimeout("window.location='"+<?php echo LINK_TO_TENBID;?>+"'", 2000);
                    //setTimeout("window.location.reload(true)",2000);
                   //$('.result').html('<div class="msg msg-thanks">Bid Submitted Successfully !</div>');

                } else{
                                        $("#checkOut_error").html(msg);
                                    }
            },
            clearForm:  false,
            resetForm:  false
        });
    },
           errorLabelContainer: "#checkOut_error",
          rules: {
                phone_number: {
                    required: true

                },
                recipient_name: {
                    required: true,
                    min_length: 6
                }

          },
          messages: {
                recipient_name: {
                    required: "Enter recipient name",
                    min_length: "Name should be atleast 6 characters long"
                }
          }
 });
```

-How to add rules and error messages?

-Which attribute does validation plugin uses: name or id?

-How to show one error message at a time?

Comment: have you read its document? I think its has information that you need. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?  What about your HTML?

Comment: **Quote OP:** _"How to should one message at a time?"_  ~ the grammar of this question is broken.  Please rephrase.

Comment: This question was relevant to me

Answer (score 10):

> -Which attribute does validation plugin uses: name or id?

[As per documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation), the plugin requires that all `input` fields contain a `name` `attribute`.  When specifying the `rules` and `messages` inside `.validate()`, you would use the `name` `attribute`.

> -How to add rules and error messages?

The `min_length` rule should **not** contain an underscore.  It's `minlength`.  Otherwise, your code looked correct.

Simple demo based on your code...

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#account_info").validate({
        rules: {
            phone_number: {
                required: true
            },
            recipient_name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6  // <-- removed underscore
            }
        },
        messages: {
            phone_number: {
                required: "this field is required"
            },
            recipient_name: {
                required: "Enter recipient name",
                minlength: "Name should be at least {0} characters long" // <-- removed underscore
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form');  // for demo
            return false;  // for demo
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="account_info">
    <input type="text" name="phone_number" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="recipient_name" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Working jsFiddle Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/rfgRL/**

---

Also, when using a rule like `minlength`, your custom message can contain a placeholder, `{0}`, that inserts your specific rule definition.

```
minlength: 6
```

with a custom message...

```
minlength: "Name should be at least {0} characters long"
```

will automatically display...

> Name should be at least 6 characters long

---

Since you only call `.validate()` *once* on DOM ready to only initialize the validation plugin with its options, there is no purpose in assigning it to a variable; it's not being re-used anywhere... at least it shouldn't be.

```
var v = jQuery("#account_info").validate({...});
```

Would simply be this...

```
jQuery("#account_info").validate({...});
```

Elsewhere in your code, if you needed to test the `form` for validity or re-trigger a validity test, [use the `.valid()` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid).  It will both return a boolean and trigger display of any pending form errors.  Example:

```
if (jQuery("#account_info").valid()) { ...
```

Comment: @EjazKarim, please "accept" my answer by clicking he green checkmark if it solved your question.

Comment: Your answer was so helpful to me mwa

Comment: @Sparky thanks for the explanation... but I wonder how to add styling to error message? I try adding `error_message_class` parameter but it doesn't work

Comment: @Abaij, hint:  `label.error`.  However, it's not appropriate to hijack comments to ask an unrelated question. Please post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple jquery registration(signup) validator :

```
        $('#submitButton').click(function() {
        $("#accounterForm").validate({
    rules: {
        firstName: "required",
        lastName: "required",
        companyName: {
            required: true,
            no_special_characters: true,
            maxlength: 64
        },
        companyFullName: "required",
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6
        },
        confirmPassword: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            equalTo: "#mid-box4"
        },
        emailId: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        firstName: "Please enter your first name",
        lastName: "Please enter your last name",
        companyName: "Please enter company ID",
        companyName: {
            required: "Please enter company ID",
            no_special_characters: "Company ID should contain atleast one letter and no special characters",
            maxlength: "Company ID exceeded the maximum length"
        },
        companyFullName: "Please enter company name",
        password: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
            minlength: "Your password must be at least 6 characters long"
        },
        confirmPassword: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
            minlength: "Your password must be at least 6 characters long",
            equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
        },
        emailId: "Please enter a valid email address",
        confirmemailId:{
        required:"Please confirm email address",
        equalTo :"Emailid and confirm emaild must be same"
        },
        agree: "Please accept Terms of use"
    }
});
```

Comment: -1 for putting `.validate()` inside of a `click` handler.  `.validate()` should be called _once_ on DOM ready to _initialize_ the plugin, **not** every time the submit button is clicked.  Your method will result in a form that does no live validation whatsoever until after the submit button is clicked, and then redundantly _re-initializes_ the plugin every time.  Additionally, the plugin already has it's own `submitHandler` that captures this same `click` event.