# Django form wizard: How to validate forms manually

Tags: django, django-formwizard

I have been reading the Form Wizard docs trying to look for a method that can modifying the request.POST **before** validating the form. It seems like there are only methods for dealing with data after `is_valid()` is called.

By **modifying** i mean:

```
  updated_request = request.POST.copy()

  updated_request.update({
       'artist': request.user.profile.person.id,
       'musicLength': 60, # Just a placeholder, will be changed during validations
  })

  mainForm = UploadSingle(updated_request, request.FILES, instance=instance)
```

The main reason for doing this is because i am using ajax, where some other data is being passed with the request. I want to be able to validate on my own rather than form wizard doing it behind the scenes

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to overide the save() fucntion of the models and create your own validation rules.

[Check this article](https://django.cowhite.com/blog/django-form-validation-and-customization-adding-your-own-validation-rules/)

Comment: No that's not what i want. I want to be able to modify the `request.POST` before instantiating like so `MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`. I mainly wanna add additional field data to `request.POST`

Answer (score 0):

The best way that works for me is the jQuery validator, you can look in more detail in this thread:

[How to add validation rules with messages in jQuery validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460925/how-to-add-validation-rules-with-messages-in-jquery-validation)

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#account_info").validate({
        rules: {
            phone_number: {
                required: true
            },
            recipient_name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6  // <-- removed underscore
            }
        },
        messages: {
            phone_number: {
                required: "this field is required"
            },
            recipient_name: {
                required: "Enter recipient name",
                minlength: "Name should be at least {0} characters long" // <-- removed underscore
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
            alert('valid form');  // for demo
            return false;  // for demo
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally found a solution. All i had to do was override either `WizardView.get_form()` or `post()`. As stated in the form wizard docs for `get_form`:

> This method constructs the form for a given step.

And `post()` is self-expalantory. I ended up overriding `post` as i needed to return a `JsonResponse` to my ajax call.